# Android: battery recharge monitor failed to autostart when device boot

Tags: android, background-process, battery, autostart

I'm trying to write an battery monitoring application, and one of its function is to keep track of the number of time being recharged and the date associated with it.

First, I wrote everything in the main activity class using SharedPreferences, and it does work. However, I wish to keep track of the number of recharge even in background, so I googled and figured that WakefulBroadcastReceiver + IntentService might be the most efficient/easy way to do it.

I was wrong. I stuck here and I think the problem I'm having right now is that the monitor (the IntentService part) doesn't even start! I think I might have put something wrong in the manifest but I just can't find it.

Here're my codes:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mobiledevices.batteryapp" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name=".RechargeMonitor"
        android:exported="false" />
</application>
```

**BootReceiver.java**

```
package com.mobiledevices.batteryapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;

public class BootReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, RechargeMonitor.class);
        startWakefulService(context, startServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

**RechargeMonitor.java**

```
package com.mobiledevices.batteryapp;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RechargeMonitor extends IntentService {

    public RechargeMonitor(){
        super("RechargeMonitor");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        this.registerReceiver(this.batteryinfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver batteryinfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getExtras().getBoolean(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PRESENT) &&
                    intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, 0)!=0 &&
                    intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, 0)==BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING){
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.PREF_NAME, 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                int count = settings.getInt("COUNT", 0);
                editor.putInt("COUNT", count+1);
                editor.commit();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

The MainActivity.java is too long so I don't post it here. However, it shouldn't have any problem with that unless I have to call either BootReceiver/RechargeMonitor in the activity file which I guess I don't have to since manifest + BootReciver should be taking care of autostart, and it won't even be a problem.

Again the problem I encounter now is RechargeMonitor doesn't seem to start (I don't see any Toast message.)

Another thing for me to make sure is that SharedPreferences should be accessible everywhere in the same application as long as I have the name right. I've seen that in several places but I need a solid answer.

Thanks!